# Avoid blocking UI when doing a lot of operations that are required to be on main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uikit, uitextview

I need to do a possibly long series of calls that must occur on the main thread (because otherwise UIKit will balk). By "long" I mean 10,000 operations lasting .1 second each on an iPad 3.

Obviously, It's probably not the best idea to just loop through all of them at once.

I don't know how to execute all these *on the main thread* while leaving enough breathing room to keep UIKit responsive and the watchdog asleep (ie. not get terminated for hogging the run loop).

Does anybody have an idea? I will be targeting iOS 5.

Specifically what I'm trying to do is cache `UITextPosition`s, because a `UITextView` is apparently taking a non-cached, iterative approach at getting `UITextPosition`s, which means it is very, very slow at doing `positionFromPosition:textview.beginningOfDocument offset:600011`, but much faster at getting `positionFromPosition:aPositionAt600000 offset:11`. In fact, in my test case, the former takes over 100 seconds *(on the main thread!)*, while the latter is virtually instantaneous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you want to do it on the main thread? The typical answer is to do these operations on a background thread, and send UI updates back to the main thread. For example, you could use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do my time consuming task and everytime it wants to update the UI, 
    // it should dispatch that back to the main queue, e.g.

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        // do my background work

        // now update the UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // update the UI accordingly
        });
    }
});
```

**Update:**

It sounds like you have to do this in the foreground, so perhaps using a `NSTimer` might be better. I'm not a big `NSTimer` guy, but it might look something like the following.

First, make sure you have a class instance variable for it:

```
NSTimer *_timer;
```

Next, you can initialize it with:

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    _timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runloop addTimer:_timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

This will then invoke the timerCallback, perhaps processing a single UITextPosition on each invocation:

```
- (void)timerCallback:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    BOOL moreTextPositionsToCalculate = ...;

    if (moreTextPositionsToCalculate)
    {
         // calculate the next UITextPosition
    }
    else
    {
         [self stopTimer];
    }
}
```

and when you're done, you could stop your timer like so:

```
- (void)stopTimer
{
    [_timer invalidate];    
    _timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: I know - that's why I specified what I am trying to do - the time-consuming work *is* the one UIKit call. UITextView does not like its `positionFromPosition:offset:` method to be called from the background, but that one call can take up to two minutes for very, very long strings.

Comment: @fzwo If that's the case, wouldn't you just include that in the portion that you dispatch to the main queue (and therefore the background queue's primary task would be the dispatching of these separate calls to the main queue). And, if that was the case, you might change the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` to `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` so you don't bury the main queue with 10000 tasks. But I would have thought that dispatching these individual invocations to the main queue one at a time gives it a chance to do other operations, too. Interesting question.

Comment: @fzwo In retrospect, I think NSTimer makes a lot of sense here, rather than a GCD background thread.

Comment: Thank you, this works! The UI feels quite sluggish, but at least it reacts at all. Wish there were a better way, safe for reimplementing UITextView (which I might actually need to do regardless...).